# No package 'sqlite3' found - sqlite3 already installed

Tags: sqlite, cmake, compilation, pkg-config

I am trying to build an open source software using cMake and Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

Came across this error:

Checking for module 'sqlite3'
  No package 'sqlite3' found

I have already downloaded and installed sqlite3:

```
sqlite3 --version
3.28.0 2019-04-16 19:49:53 884b4b7e502b4e991677b53971277adfaf0a04a284f8e483e2553d0f83156b50
```

Folder containing these files are added as well in the `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` (and already did a restart):

- sqlite3.dll
- sqlite3.def
- sqlite3.exe
- even have sqldiff.exe, sqlite3_analyzer in the same folder.

What should I do?? Or perhaps is there a way to force cmake to use the one in my local rather than still looking for the package in `pkg-config`??

All other references online are only referring to Linux :(

Comment: On Linux and on Windows `pkg-config` looks for `.pc` file. Do you have the one in your sqlite3 installation? Variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` should point to a directory with the `.pc` file.

Comment: Wow, thanks!! That resolves it!